# Issue while logging in with VMware vSphere client 5.5

Tags: vmware

I am getting below error while logging in with VMware vSphere Client 5.5

**"The type initializer for 'VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.ClientsXml' threw an exception."**

Comment: please help me out here

Answer (score 3):

Just recently had this.  Try to right click the shortcut and "run as administrator".  This worked for me.

To avoid having to do this all the time.  Set the shortcut to "Run as administrator".  Even if a user launches it.  I should still start without prompting for an administrator ID.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem this morning, don't know what's causing the issue. Vsphere client was working fine last week, only changes was backup by Veeam during the weekend.
My solution is open the website of your ESXi server, click the "Download Vsphere client" link to download the latest version 5.5 client and upgrade the existing client.

Answer (score 1):

Check your disk space and/or file permissions of your temporary directory.

VMWare may be unable to create necessary files in your **%temp%** directory which 'will' cause the exact error your experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently, it happened because I had updated the user's TEMP file location in Control Panel - System - Advanced System Settings so TEMP files were stored on e: drive, but the temp folder path on the e: drive did not exist. Creating the correct folder structure on e drive fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to Run as Administrator, This is due to a Permissions access problem by simply double clicking it, even in an Administrative level profile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer was quite simple the C drive was full so after clearing it out a bit it now works great.